# Continuous total from only one cell to another as it grows

Tags: google-sheets, calculator, cumulative-sum

I am hoping to calculate a total as is grows or decreases using only 1 row and only 2 cells in this row. I'm wondering if it this is even possible with a formula (not a script):

Scenerio:

1. A1 and A2 have a Value of 0
   (A2 is the running total of A1, whenever a number is entered into A1 and Enter is pressed, this number will add to the value of A2)
2. A1 has 2 entered into it and Enter is press (Cell changed)
3. A2 adds this to its 0, becoming 2.
4. A1's 2 is deleted, but A2 remains 2.
5. A1 has 3 entered into it and Enter is press (Cell changed)
6. A2 becomes 5

(The only way to add or subtract from A2 is enter - or + number into A1, otherwise A2 remains the current total)

I hope this is clear. I would like all things isolated to a single row, so a normal running total does not work for this case.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with formulas.  They don't work that way.  But it would be pretty easy with a script.  On every edit of A1, adds its value to A2.  If A1 is blanked, leave A2 unchanged.  If a script answer will work for you, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to accomplish this task you will need to adjust your Spreadsheet settings.

For your specific case scenario where you just want to add (or subtract) only **once** the value of `A1` to `A2` you would need to head over your Spreadsheet menu bar and select **File->Spreadsheet Settings-> Calculation**. In that tab you should turn on `Iterative calculation` and set the `Recalculation` to `on Change` and the `Maximum number of iterations` to `1` .

Finally set `A2` formula to be `= A1 + A2`. Every time you change `A1` its value will be added (or subtracted if it is a negative value) to `A2`.

#### Reference

[Choose how often formulas should recalculate](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515)

Comment: OH MY GOSH! This is amazing, It's exactly what I needed, thank you so much! Months I've pondered this and just could not find the answer.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, I have other formulas that update based on the date, for example how a so far ahead or behind someone is on a project =ROUND(IF(C7="Small",(W7-(Y7*1.5)),W7-Y7)*-1). It didn't effect any other formulas of this nature so far, will these continue to work like normal? Again thank you so much!

Comment: @Mateo, I hadn't thought that was possible - very good application of a little known setting.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Yes, normal formulas that are not iterative calculations will remain in the same way they were.